# How to encode finite state machine as a binary string?

Tags: state-machine

How to encode / decode Finite state machines as a binary strings?

```
F: [0,1,00,01,...] -> [fsm1, fsm2,...], |fsm1|=<|fsm2|
Decode: Binary string -> FSM
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To represent an FSM, state diagrams can be encoded in DOT format:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DOT_%28graph_description_language%29

To implement an FSM in hardware, a Hardware Description Language is the appropriate tool:
https://www.microsemi.com/document-portal/doc_view/130043-state-machine-an

To implement an FSM in software, the machine can be captured with one or two look-up tables.

One LUT would be sufficient for Mealy machines, where outputs are defined with state transitions: each (state, input) combination would index to a (state, output) tuple.

Moore machines - where outputs are determined by state - would require a second look-up: the above table would yield only the state, with a second table mapping that state to its output.

Once these tables are represented in your format of choice, say JSON, then serialization should be easy.